# How can I render a Material UI grid using React without the unique key warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using React and Material UI for this project, and need to render a grid where the rows are from an array of data and the columns contain specific information like this:

```html
<Grid container>
  {myData.map((record) => (
    <>
      <Grid item>{record.field1}</Grid>
      <Grid item>{record.field2}</Grid>
      <Grid item>{record.field3}</Grid>
    </>
  )}
</Grid>
```

This of course results in the React warning about items in the list not having unique keys.

The problem is that `< key={index}>` is not valid in React, and replacing `<>` with an actual tag like `<div>` for example messes up the grid; which expects grid items to be directly contained within the grid container.

Is there any way to work around this problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can pass `key`'s to an explicit `<React.Fragment>` component (which `<>` is [short hand](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax) for).

[React Docs - Keyed Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#keyed-fragments):

> Fragments declared with the explicit <React.Fragment> syntax may have
> keys. A use case for this is mapping a collection to an array of
> fragments — for example, to create a description list:
>
> ```
> function Glossary(props) {
>   return (
>     <dl>
>       {props.items.map(item => (
>         // Without the `key`, React will fire a key warning
>         <React.Fragment key={item.id}>
>           <dt>{item.term}</dt>
>           <dd>{item.description}</dd>
>         </React.Fragment>
>       ))}
>     </dl>
>   );
> }
> ```
>
> key is the only attribute that can be passed to Fragment. In the
> future, we may add support for additional attributes, such as event
> handlers.